# How to separate letters and digits from a string in php

Tags: php, string, substring

I have a string which is combination of letters and digits. For my application i have to separate a string with letters and digits:  ex:If my string is "12jan" i hav to get "12" "jan" separately..

Comment: a more general regex for word and number split may be useful, [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#111695).

Answer (score 32):

```
$numbers = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $str);
$letters = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', $str);
```

Comment: [You don't need to invoke the regex engine twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311156/how-to-separate-letters-and-digits-from-a-string-in-php/4311202#4311202).

Comment: @alex, if it's a matter of speed, what I posted is faster in my test (100000 iterations). I believe it's clearer too.

Comment: It is faster, by about 3 times time in my tests. I'm not which one is clearer though.

Comment: There are [simpler ways to express digits and non-digits in a regex pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65704778/2943403).

Answer (score 19):

You can make use of `preg_split` to split your string at the point which is preceded by digit and is followed by letters as:

```
$arr = preg_split('/(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-z]+)/i',$str);
```

[**Code in Action**](http://codepad.org/fXwLOrEC)

```
<?php
$str = '12jan';
$arr = preg_split('/(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-z]+)/i',$str);                                                               
print_r($arr);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => jan
)
```

Comment: your code is not working if there is whitespace. `$str = 12 Jan` like that

Comment: If there's a whitespace, wouldn't it be easier to use explode using the space itself as a delimiter?

Comment: @PrashantTapase just add space in the character set `[a-z]` : `[\sa-z]`

Comment: This code works only if digits are first. If You will change $str to 'jan12' it will output [0] => 'jan12'

Answer (score 10):

```
$string = "12312313sdfsdf24234";
preg_match_all('/([0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+)/',$string,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

this might work alot better

Comment: givng out put Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
        )

)

Comment: Why bother with the capture grouping? I'd probably use a case insensitively flag. This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 9):

```
preg_match_all('/^(\d+)(\w+)$/', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);

$day = $matches[1][0];
$month = $matches[2][0];
```

Of course, this only works when your strings are exactly as described *"abc123"* (with no whitespace appended or prepended).

If you want to get all numbers and characters, you can do it with one regex.

```
preg_match_all('/(\d)|(\w)/', $str, $matches);

$numbers = implode($matches[1]);
$letters = implode($matches[2]);

var_dump($numbers, $letters);
```

[See it!](http://ideone.com/hsOCP)

Comment: This presumes that the string won't be jan12 or fg1dg34sdf.

Comment: `preg_match_all('/(\d)|(.)|(\w)/', $str, $matches);` will also respect strings like '12-jan' or 'jan-12', if you want to reuse the extracted characters too.

Comment: The commented code by MrMacvos is misleading/bad, but I cannot dv it.  **Do not use it.**  https://3v4l.org/9tDfr and https://3v4l.org/INJ1H

Answer (score 4):

You can split the string by matching sequences of digits or non-digits, then "forgetting" the matched characters with `\K`.

```
preg_split(
    '~(?:\d+|\D+)\K~',
    $string,
    0,
    PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY
)
```

Or you could use matched digits as the delimiter and retain the delimiters in the output.

```
preg_split(
    '~(\d+)~',
    $string,
    0,
    PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE 
)
```

A [demonstration](https://3v4l.org/gV56K) of both techniques.

---

If you know the order of your numeric and alphabetic substrings, then `sscanf()` is a perfect tool.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VbfF6))

```
var_export(sscanf('12jan', '%d%s'));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 12,
  1 => 'jan',
)
```

Notice how `12` is conveniently cast as an integer as well.

`sscanf()` also allows individual variables to be assigned if desired (`$day` and `$month`) as the 3rd and 4th parameters.

Comment: This will produce many groups when the numbers and letters are interwoven.

Comment: Of course it will.  What's the alternative? The [mcve] is so narrowly scoped that I have no way to guess how the desired output should differ if the input is extended.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me as per my requirement, you can edit as per yours

```
function stringSeperator($string,$type_return){

    $numbers =array();
    $alpha = array();
    $array = str_split($string);
    for($x = 0; $x< count($array); $x++){
        if(is_numeric($array[$x]))
            array_push($numbers,$array[$x]);
        else
            array_push($alpha,$array[$x]);
    }// end for         

    $alpha = implode($alpha);
    $numbers = implode($numbers);

    if($type_return == 'number')    
    return $numbers;
    elseif($type_return == 'alpha')
    return $alpha;

}// end function
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.  Why not just use iterated string concatenating techniques if you are going to return strings?  Using temporary arrays and imploding seems unnecessarily wasteful.

Answer (score -1):

Try This :

```
$string="12jan";
$chars = '';
$nums = '';
for ($index=0;$index<strlen($string);$index++) {
    if(isNumber($string[$index]))
        $nums .= $string[$index];
    else    
        $chars .= $string[$index];
}
echo "Chars: -$chars-<br>Nums: -$nums-";


function isNumber($c) {
    return preg_match('/[0-9]/', $c);
}
```

Comment: in some versions it is is_numeric()

Comment: Calling `preg_match()` inside of a custom function for EVERY character in a string -- that's WAY too much overhead for this task.  I would not recommend that any researchers use this option.  As a result, I have dv'ed and voted to delete this answer.