# How to separate letters and digits from a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a string which is combination of letters and digits. For my application I have to separate a string with letters and digits: ex:If my string is "12jan" i hav to get "12" "jan" seperately..

Comment: didnt you just ask this question?
look for the answers there
you can use the same regular expressions with some minor
modification and it will work with javascript aswell

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311156/how-to-separate-letters-and-digits-from-a-string-in-php/4311176#4311176

Answer (score 7):

You can always do this if `str` is your string:

```
var digits = str.replace(/\D/g, ""),
    letters = str.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, "");
```

Essentially, what this code does is replace all of the characters that you do not want with the empty string.

`\D` and `[^a-z]` are character classes that represent, respectively, all the non-digits and all the non-letters. The `g` at the end of the two expressions makes them replace all occurrences of the pattern. The `i` make it case-insensitive, keeping both lower and upper case letters.

Answer (score 1):

Well for the example you gave I would try

```
parseInt(num)
```

so if you had `parseInt(12Jan);`
you should get 12.

I am not an expert so I hope this helps.