# PHP function to separate integer and string part from a given string variable

Tags: php, string

I have a string variable `$nutritionalInfo`, this can have values like 100gm, 10mg, 400cal, 2.6Kcal, 10percent etc... I want to parse this string and separate the value and unit part into two variables `$value` and `$unit`. Is there any php function available for this? Or how can I do this in php?

Comment: Use regex: `preg_match_all('/(?P<digit>\d+(?:\.\d+))(?P<unit>\w+)/', $string, $matches);print_r($matches);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use preg_match_all, like this

```
$str = "100gm";
preg_match_all('/^(\d+)(\w+)$/', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);

$int = $matches[1][0];
$letters = $matches[2][0];
```

For float value try this

```
$str = "100.2gm";
preg_match_all('/^(\d+|\d*\.\d+)(\w+)$/', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);

$int = $matches[1][0];
$letters = $matches[2][0];
```

Comment: Thanks @HamZaDzCyberDeV well it was a good workaround though.

Comment: Won't match units such as mico grams, for example `5µg`

Answer (score 4):

Use regexp.

```
$str = "12Kg";
preg_match_all('/^(\d+|\d*\.\d+)(\w+)$/', $str, $matches);
echo "Value is - ".$value = $matches[1][0];
echo "\nUnit is - ".$month = $matches[2][0];
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/HjMH2t)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem but none of the answers here worked for me.  The problem with the other answers is they all assume you'll always have a unit.  But sometimes I would have plain numbers like "100" instead of "100kg" and the other solutions would cause the value to be "10" and the units to be "0".

Here's a better solution I somewhat took from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4311416/5557235).  This will separate the number from ANY non-number characters.

```
$str = '70%';

$values = preg_split('/(?<=[0-9])(?=[^0-9]+)/i', $str);

echo 'Value: ' . $values[0]; // Value: 70
echo '<br/>';
echo 'Units: ' . $values[1]; // Units: %
```