# i want text and numeric part from the string in php

Tags: php, string

i have one string

```
$str ='california 94063';
```

now i want california and 94063 both in diferent variable.
string can be anything

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Is the string layout always the same? e.g. `<something something> <number>`?

Comment: no it can be anything eg:-'123 hello' or '123568 tye 345'

Comment: Possible dupliacte of [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311156/how-to-separate-letters-and-digits-from-a-string-in-php)

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
$strings = explode(' ', $str);
```

Assuming that your string has ' ' as a separator.

Then, if you want to find the numeric entries of the `$strings` array, you can use [is_numeric](http://uk.php.net/is_numeric) function.

Comment: Frustrated i suppose. Im voting up.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
list($str1,$str2)=explode(' ',$str);
echo $str2;
```

Comment: Why `explode` two times? Either use a variable and access it as an array (see Yellow Bird's answer), or use `list` to get two variables.

Comment: This is considering that the source string only have two "words". The OP said that the "string can be anything"

Answer (score 1):

If your string layout is always the same (say: follows a given format) then I'd use `sscanf` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php).

`list($str, $number) = sscanf('california 94063, "%str %d");`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str ='california 94063';
$x = preg_match('(([a-zA-Z]*) ([0-9]*))',$str, $r);
echo 'String Part='. $r[1];
echo "<br />";
echo 'Number Part='.$r[2];
?>
```

If text pattern can be changed then I found this solution
Source :: 
[How to separate letters and digits from a string in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311156/how-to-separate-letters-and-digits-from-a-string-in-php)

```
<?php
$string="94063 california";
$chars = '';
$nums = '';
for ($index=0;$index<strlen($string);$index++) {
    if(isNumber($string[$index]))
        $nums .= $string[$index];
    else    
        $chars .= $string[$index];
}
echo "Chars: -".trim($chars)."-<br>Nums: -".trim($nums)."-";


function isNumber($c) {
    return preg_match('/[0-9]/', $c);
}
?>
```

Comment: hello @rohit awasthi if the string is '94063 california' then?