# How to split out string by symbols using preg_split?

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I have for example string `$s = 'A5C7';` and `$s = 'A5C17';`

I was try split string by symbols using `preg_split('//', $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`

If string `$s = 'A5C7'` I got OK result like this:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "C"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "7"
}
```

but if use `$s = 'A5C17'`
I got:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "C"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "7"
}
```

I wanna got like this:

```
 array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "A"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "5"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "C"
      [3]=>
      string(1) "17"
    }
```

How to improve `preg_split('//', $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);` for getting both type of results?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to separate letters and digits from a string in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311156/how-to-separate-letters-and-digits-from-a-string-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the pattern `//` will split characters. Try this instead:

```
preg_split('/(\\d+)/', $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

array (
  0 => 'A',
  1 => '5',
  2 => 'C',
  3 => '17',
);
```

This pattern uses groups of consecutive integers as split delimiters, and it will capture what's between them. The option `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` makes it captures the delimiters (the integers) as well.