# PHP: Using preg_split to separate letters and numbers

Tags: php, regex

Using **preg_split** on **PHP**, I want to separate letters and numbers, and ignore others (symbols, tab, space, etc).
For example:

```
"A/BC 1"     => array("A","BC","1")
"A1-BCD/2"   => array("A","1","BCD","2")
"A1BC23-45"  => array("A","1","BC","23","45"), not array("A1BC23","45")
"ABC###123"  => array("ABC","123")
"AB+C^12/34" => array("AB","C","12","34")
```

What pattern must be written?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to separate letters and digits from a string in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311156/how-to-separate-letters-and-digits-from-a-string-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = [
"A/BC 1",
"A1-BCD/2",
"A1BC23-45",
"ABC***123",
"AB+C^12/34",
];
foreach ($arr as $ele) {
    preg_match_all('/[A-Z]+|\d+/', $ele, $m);
    print_r($m[0]);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => BC
    [2] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => 1
    [2] => BCD
    [3] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => 1
    [2] => BC
    [3] => 23
    [4] => 45
)
Array
(
    [0] => ABC
    [1] => 123
)
Array
(
    [0] => AB
    [1] => C
    [2] => 12
    [3] => 34
)
```

Comment: So, I must use preg_match_all, not preg_split? Thank you. Excuse me, my knowledge about PHP functions is not good.

Comment: @Mawan: It will be much more complex to do same think with preg_split.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $str = "A/BC 1, A1-BCD/2, A1BC23-45, ABC***123, AB+C^12/34";
    $e = explode(',', $str);
    $arr = [];
    foreach ($e as $value){
        preg_match_all('/\w+/', $value, $matches);
        $s = '';
        foreach ($matches as $match){
            foreach ($match as $m){
                $s .= $m . " ";
            }
            $arr[] = $s;
        }

    }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arr);
```